# APN not working from the AppStore build

Tags: ios, app-store, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We have created iOS application that uses APN. It was working fine in the development environment. We are getting APN notification in the development environment. But in the production environment (from the AppStore) the APN are not getting. We have found lots of question related to this topic in the net. And we have cross checked our app with that check points. But now way. The APN related details about our application and server are given below.

App details.

•   Configured the bundle id for APN services
•   Generated Production Push SSL Certificate/Development  Push SSL Certificate
•   Downloaded the certificates and installed on the keychain successfully
•   Then exported the apple distribution push certificate and key as.p12
•   Converted the .p12 files to .pem and concatenated the .pem files of certificate and key
•   Installed it on the Server(gateway.push.apple.com) at port 2195
•   In the application the aps-environment key with "production" as its value.

While checking the application binary of adhoc(distribution(ipa)) build on device, the notification is registered successfully and we could get the device token. But not getting any notification alerts on device.

The device token which we have generated is : 612e0899 722d2e2f 06dad688 64089023 50d910d6 a3cc00ec bd798915 3efef503

Server Details.

In the server (provider) setup the production environment (gateway.push.apple.com), not the sandbox environment (gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com). Our server is ROR. And we are using https://github.com/jpoz/APNS gem for sending APNs. The port we are using is 2195.

Any one can help us? We are stuck here for last 4 days. How can we test the build we are going to upload in the AppStore before uploading it using the actual production environment in the APNs. So that we can avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and the solution turned out to be really odd in my case. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12670448/679059