# App Download from App Store got BadDeviceToken, build from source does not

Tags: ios, django, apple-push-notifications

I have searched over the Stackoverflow, but none of them answer to my questions
Build from Xcode APNS works, but App Store version my backend raises `BadDeviceToken`.

The `Success` are `registration_id` made by build from source

```sh
In [1]: APNSDevice.objects.all().send_message("test")
Out[1]:
[{'27321a3d872613499e27638733e9d1da7e6aa52888a2d90769b150f6339360b1': 'Success',
  '798a23a46169e405c41a0c9f44faa0acd39a65119960b973acd248a6de1d624e': 'Success',
  '1d742a9ae1684fed5e6c672587ee27c1523cc97e931cc64f108f7c4924aba2af': 'DeviceTokenNotForTopic',
  '27173de1aed3a065644708602fd5659cf4e0f8c3ce5b3ef7c4b0769655b92041': 'DeviceTokenNotForTopic',
  'e5647247877a0e1db3c7b52821b4230551267ca8a360f862ec5dde506e9b2f36': 'Success',
  '0eecae0cb6f4c27ee4b915e37dbb9c7cc84e4967e71c8efab808e231f46b8ec6': 'BadDeviceToken',
  '582d6a7c4628131cba9d0dfa9096cc81e3b48f6b6409252515d7402ef1c3ef30': 'BadDeviceToken'}]
```

I don't care `DeviceTokenNotForTopic` for now. Just stay focus on `BadDeviceToken`

**Step to reproduce are**:

1. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250510/generate-pem-file-used-to-set-up-apple-push-notifications#21253261) to get `.p12` file
2. Then make `.pem` from [doc](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications/blob/master/docs/APNS.rst). I must put `passphrase` to `key` otherwise I can not proceed next step
3. Download my own app from App Store and login to get `registration_id`

**Checkings:**

1. `pushtry.com` I upload `.p12` and put `registration_id`. It works I can get `push notification`
2. `openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert aps-cert.pem -key aps-key-noenc.pem` also works without any problem. The connection still remain

**My configuration:**
Django3
django-push-notification @master commit: `c610dd9c7871f4e81bdffce783df8b040ca22878`

`settings.py`

```
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS['APNS_CERTIFICATE'] = str(APPS_DIR) + '/push_noti/dd/aps.pem'
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS['APNS_USE_SANDBOX'] = "gateway.push.apple.com:2195"
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS['APNS_TOPIC'] = "com.multy.herr.reviews"
```

I had tried with the same `production` APNS cert according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/)

Development server: api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443
Production server: api.push.apple.com:443

However, all giving me same `BadDevieToken`

**FYI:**
I am using `production` APNS cert

I take care only Django backend. My iOS developer upload app from his computer. I am not sure this will be problematic or not

I had tried `fastlane` with `pushtry.com` again `.p12` works, but `.pem` does not. It pop up dialog `production_com.xxx.yyy.zzz.pem | 3883 | application/x-x509-ca-cert`

**Question:**

Where am I wrong?

**Another Solution:**
I might use AWS SNS to deal with this

Comment: I found this one, urging my iOS developer confirm this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660931/cant-register-for-push-notifications-while-using-production-certificate-only/12670448#12670448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Wyetro is correct. The problem comes from that line I was confused with document and codebase at certain level in the lib itself it use `bool`

`PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS['APNS_USE_SANDBOX'] = False`

Then I can be able to send out message

Comment: Glad you got it figured out

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [README for django-push-notification](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications/blob/c610dd9c7871f4e81bdffce783df8b040ca22878/README.rst):

```
If you are planning on running your project with APNS_USE_SANDBOX=True, 
then make sure you have set the development certificate as your APNS_CERTIFICATE.
```

So the issue is with the line:

```
PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS['APNS_USE_SANDBOX'] = "gateway.push.apple.com:2195"
```

For more information on the difference between using APN for debug vs release builds of an app you should read [iOS APNS Development [sandbox] vs Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554638/ios-apns-development-sandbox-vs-production)

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I am using `prod` APNS and I had tried 2 more different APNS url according to this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/ Development server: api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443
Production server: api.push.apple.com:443